# Multithreading practices and methods using C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm looking for good examples of multithreading practices in C#. I'd like to see common methods of executing multithreading processes.

Comment: This is very vague.  Did you try a search on those tags? Do you have a specific scenario in mind?

Comment: Review the boatload of existing questions on StackOverflow on this topic: [C# and multithreading tags, "best practices"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+[multithreading]+best+practices)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been doing the same type of research. I've come across a free eBook on threading which has been fantastic. It's from Joseph Albahari, the author of several books and LinqPad. Excellent resource.

```
http://www.albahari.com/threading/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about what kind of patterns and problems you might stumble into when doing multithreaded concurrent programming in general I've heard a lot of good about. For C# specifics  Albahari's book or C# 4.0 in a nutshell is a good reference

[http://www.amazon.com/Concurrent-Programming-Windows-Joe-Duffy/dp/032143482X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X)